# Want to correctly replace the 'not in' query with the 'not exists' query

Tags: sql

I wanted to replace this 'in' and 'not in' query to 'exists' and 'not exists' query.

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE A.key1 NOT IN (
        SELECT key1
        FROM A
        GROUP BY key1
        HAVING COUNT(key1) = 1
        )

UNION

SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE A.key1 IN (
        SELECT key1
        FROM A
        GROUP BY key1
        HAVING COUNT(key1) = 1
        )
```

I tried this query, but it was useless.

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM A
        GROUP BY key1
        HAVING COUNT(key1) = 1
        )

UNION

SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT key1
        FROM A
        GROUP BY key1
        HAVING COUNT(key1) = 1
        )
```

How can I replace the correct query?

Comment: The sub-queries need references to the outer queries!

Answer (score 0):

Add `where` condition as below to maintain reference with the outer query

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM A AS A1
        WHERE A1.key1 = a.key1
        GROUP BY A1.key1
        HAVING COUNT(A1.key1) = 1
        )
```

Comment: Have different table aliases for A, and qualify all columns!

Comment: Can i replace this query to use 'exists' & 'not exists' ?  "select * from a where (a.key1, a.key2) in ( select b.key1, b.key2 from b )"

Comment: @jarlh Is that query right? I think that query isn't replace correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
SELECT *
FROM A T
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT key1
        FROM A
        GROUP BY key1
        HAVING COUNT(key1) = 1
        and MAX(key1) = T.key1
        )
UNION

SELECT *
FROM A T
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT key1
        FROM A
        GROUP BY key1
        HAVING COUNT(key1) = 1
        and MAX(key1) = T.key1
        )
```

Comment: Is it possible to execute in Spark(2.0) ??

Comment: I dont know, you need to test for see the result.